# How to include directories in classpath of Intellij run configuration

Tags: intellij-idea

For the past 10 years, I was a user of Eclipse and now moving on IntelliJ. We are using multiple .launch configuration for single application in eclipse as per the different directories (contains properties files and not part of project) in classpath. 
[image]
However I did not find to set directory on run configuration level in IntelliJ and due to this limitation now creating different IntelliJ project for each run configuration and flipping windows of IntelliJ.
DO we have any way to set Directories in run configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the directory, which you want to add in the class path.

And then select option "mark directory as" with different options e.g. "Sources Route", "Resources Route" etc.

Apply the option as per the need.

Comment: So we need to mark it as per the requirement and we can not bind it with run configuration. It seems a limitation of IntelliJ.